# Ошибка в наследовании класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-3.6

```
class Hero():
    def __init__(self,name,level,rank):
        self.__name = name
        self.__level = level
        self.__rank = rank

    def levelUp(self):
         self.__level += 1

    def showData(self):
        data = (self.__name + " " + str(self.__level) + " " + str(self.__rank))
        print(data)

    class SuperHero(Hero):
    def __init__(self,name,level,rank,magic):
        super().__init__(name,level,rank)
        self.__magic = magic

    def makeMagic(self):
        self.__magic -= 10

    def showData(self):
        data = (self.__name + " " + str(self.__level) + " " + str(self.__rank) + " " + str(self.__magic))
        print(data)
```

Ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'SuperHero' object has no attribute '_SuperHero__name'

Comment: Вы в классе Hero атрибут name объявили приватным двойное подчёркивание в питоне это приватность т.е. атрибут доступен только в этом классе

Comment: @Александр а что мне сделать,чтобы ему нельзя бы изменять таким кодом objHero.name = "..." 
но и чтобы было доступно в классе наследнике?

Comment: @Александр https://ibb.co/hTSiEp что-то не так??

Comment: Я не понимаю что вы хотите )

Comment: @Александр хотя бы чтобы оно работало)))

Comment: Вы сами задачу придумали?

Comment: @Александр да, так для себя попробовать наследование

Comment: Что бы использовать атрибут name в SuperHero его сначала надо создать)

Comment: @Александр  Окей,спасибо, работает если уберу свойства приватности
А как сделать, чтобы никто не мог менять например objHero.name = "..." ?)

Comment: Вы лучше чем что то сочинять почитайте про ОПП в питоне и поймите  прочитанное это  займёт около года) потом вопросов таких не будет ещё посмотрите скаченные библиотеки как там всё устроенно

Comment: Приватный атрибут он для того и приватный чтобы его нельзя было изменить извне